# Is there any way to get Linq-to-entities to evaluate a local expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Lets say you have the following linq expression:

```
from o in salesEntities.Orders where o.OrderDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20) select o
```

Entity Framework does not know how to translate DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20) into an Entity SQL expression, and you get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So here is my questions: Is there any way to get Linq to Entities to evaluate part of the lambda expression and substitute a constant value, without me having to declare a local variable to hold it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.  Everything in a linq to entities expression must be either in a local variable or able to be translated into a sql expression by the entity framework.

Answer (score 9):

LINQ-to-Entities can deal with local values but not local expressions.  Your code will work with this minor change:

`var pastDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20);`

`from o in salesEntities.Orders where o.OrderDate < pastDate select o`

Comment: This is right. In the cases where you actually do need `AddDays` in the query (this isn't one of them), use the `EntityFunctions` type.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to EntityFunctions... didn't know about that.  handy!

Comment: As I asked at the end of the question, can this be done without a local variable? I've just written a query with 8 different constant dates in it, so now I have 8 extra local variables cluttering up my code. There _should_ be a way to say just execute this bit and pass the result in the query.

Comment: @Darren, you can do this without a local using the `EntityFunctions` type.

Comment: Sorry @Craig, I get that, I was wondering if there was some way to make any .NET function that did not have inputs from the entities evaluate locally before translation. Then I could write "where date > LastPublicHoliday(DateTime.Today)" or some other random function. I think the answer is going to be no!

Answer (score 5):

Change your expression using the EntityFunction for add days like this:

```
var result =
(
from o in salesEntities.Orders 
where o.OrderDate < System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Today,-20) 
select o
);
```

Comment: This no longer works in entity framework 6. Use this instead: System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays